# Unable to split the string properly

Tags: .net, vb.net, split

## Code Logic

I'm trying to read *file_path* and *file_hash* stored in a list of string. They both are seperated by " |+| " as delimeter.
I want to read them into a temporary array "tempArray()" where file_path will take the index 0 and file_hash will take the index 1.

## Problem

Unable to perform String.Split() for seperation. Tried 2 solutions after searching.

## Tested But Not Working

- `Dim tempArray() As String = filepathhash.Split(" |+| ")`
- `Dim tempArray() As String = filepathhash.Split(New [Char]() {CChar(" "), CChar("|"), CChar("+"), CChar("|"), CChar(" ")})`

## Full Code

```
For Each filepathhash In se_queryfile_hashes
  MsgBox(filepathhash.ToString)
  'Dim tempArray() As String = filepathhash.Split(New [Char]() {CChar(" "), CChar("|"), CChar("+"), CChar("|"), CChar(" ")}) ' |+|
   Dim tempArray() As String = filepathhash.Split(" |+| ") ' not working too..
   MsgBox(tempArray(0)) : MsgBox(tempArray(1)) 'testing using msgbox
   For Each malwarehash In temp_hash_values
      If tempArray(1) = malwarehash Then
         matched_files.Add(tempArray(0))
         matched_hashes.Add(tempArray(1))
      End If
      check_bgWorkerCancelled()
   Next
   tempcounter += 1
Next
```

## Expected

I expect the results to be:

- MsgBox1 will display `C:/some/folder/file.exe`
- Msgbox2 will display `FileHashForTheAboveFile`

## What I Get

I get unexpected results with both the ways of String.Split(). They both split chunks with blank spaces and everything else, but not from the delimeter set.

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7QKK.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `Dim tempArray() As String = filepathhash.Split({" |+| "}, StringSplitOptions.None)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you using vb.net you can use VB split function instead of .NET

```
Dim tempArray() As String = split(filepathhash," |+| ")
```